# Wordpress php issue with php8 and above

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the following code in my functions.php, which works fine in php7.4. The code is for a text button share button for pinterest, which grabs the post url, the post featured image and the post title. It works fine on PHP 7.4, but on PHP8 and above it throws the following errors:

---

Warning: Undefined variable $post in \wp-content\themes\theme2\functions.php on line 280

Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in \wp-content\themes\theme2\functions.php on line 280

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in \wp-content\themes\theme2\functions.php on line 286

---

For reference, line 280 is:

`$srlThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );`

and line 286 is:

`$pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$srlURL.'&media='.$srlThumbnail[0].'&description='.$srlTitle;`

Can anyone let me know how to make this work with PHP8+? Thanks.

This is the functions.php code in full:

---

```
    function srl_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    if(is_singular( 'post' )){

    // Get current page URL 
    $srlURL = get_permalink();

    // Get current page title
    $srlTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

    // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
    $srlThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

    $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$srlURL.'&description='.$srlTitle;
    $content .= '<a rel="nofollow noopener" class="srl-link srl-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank" aria-label="Share on Pinterest" title="Share on Pinterest">Pin It</a>';

    return $content;
    }else{
    // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
    return $content;
    }
    };

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'srl_social_sharing_buttons');
```

Comment: As the error says, `$post` is not defined. Use `global $post` in your function or `get_the_ID()` the remainder of your error is because $post is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

*As the error message said:* the variable **$post** is Undefined, so the **wp_get_attachment_image_src()** function return a bool (false) value instead of an array if it found the attachment image.

Solution is put this line (to get the **current post object**):

```
global $post;
```

right below this line:

```
if(is_singular( 'post' )){
```